# Query tool for Oracle 9

Tags: database, oracle

I'm used to the comfort of working with MSSQL and the Enterprise Manager and Query Analyzer. Now working with Oracle 9.2 and having to suffer using SQL Plus for making queries, I'm looking for some better alternatives. Are there any free or low-cost tools for this purpose?

Comment: No matter what tool you go with, you'll have to get used to Oracle having explicit commits, vs implicit ones in MSSQL.

If you insert, update, delete, and you are sure you want to do it, click the commit button, or execute "commit;"

Comment: I'm sorry, AFTER your insert, update, delete, and you are sure, you must commit so others can view the data in their sessions.  Also, you may be locking tables until you commit, so be careful on production systems.

Comment: Thanks, that's valuable advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html)

Free, Oracle supported, nice UI, type ahead syntatic help, schema comparison, script generation, data import / export, etc etc.

Comment: For MSSQL converts, especially - go to Tools, Preferences, Database, NLS Parameters, and set your date format to be yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss

Otherwise, you are going to be very frustrated with the default date format.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed it, looks very promising

Answer (score 1):

Try Toad: http://www.toadsoft.com/toad_oracle.htm

Answer (score 1):

toad is the tool you're looking for. you can acquire it here : http://www.toadsoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Developer yopu can connect to your SQL Server database.
http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/08-may/o38sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [Devart's OraDeveloper Studio](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/), a powerful development environment for working with Oracle, that has built-in visual query builder and supports Oracle versions from 7.3 to 11g.

Retail price is only $99.95 per license.